# How to copy the output of a python program to a text file? (cannot use the console, only the Python IDLE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, text-files, python-idle

I want my program to execute in python IDLE and then the last output has to be saved in a text file.

Here's my code:

```py
while (True):
    import random
    import time

    #Introduction
    print("""                                            You are in the Kingdom of Dragons. In front of you, you see two caves. In one
                                                cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you. The other
                                                               dragon is hungry and will eat you on sight!
                                                               
""")



    #letting the player input 1 or 2
    while True:
        select = input("cave 1,2,3,4 or 5 : ")
        if (select=="1") or (select=="2") or (select=="3") or (select=="4") or (select=="5"):
            break

    #some statements of the game
    print("""\nYou approach the cave...""",select)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("""A large dragon jumps out in front of you!""")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("""He opens his jaws and ...""")

    time.sleep(3)

    #luck
    choices = ["Gobbles you down!","Greets you before share his teature"]
    print("\n",random.choice(choices))

    time.sleep(2)
    
    again = input("\nDo you wanna play again?(y/n)")
    if again=="y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I want this game's last output in the idle to be saved in a text file. It has to be done using some source codes. (not manually)

I did try a lot methods which are in stack overflow but those are NOT the solutions.

The methods I used which doesn't work for MY program:

1.

```py
import io
import sys

def foo():
    print("hello world, what else ?")

stream = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream
try:
    foo()
finally:
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

print(stream.getvalue())`
```

2. 

```py
# Open a file in write mode
    with open('lastgame.txt', 'w') as file:
    
        # Redirect the output to the file
        sys.stdout = file`
   """then my program"""
   `# Reset the output to the console
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`
```

and many more on stack overflow.

I want the "last output" (not the others, only the output I executed the last) of my program also executed in IDLE and then save it in a text file.(not manually, not using the console, only on python IDLE)

Comment: *You* need to save the current value of `sys.stdout`, and restore it after the code you want to capture output from.  `sys.__stdout__` is not usable here; it's the original output channel, that doesn't actually go anywhere (since IDLE is a GUI application), NOT the output channel that IDLE actually uses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to sub-class `io.TextIOWrapper` and override the `write()` method. There might be a cleaner way to do this, but this half assed implementation seems to work for me:

```py
import io
import random
import sys
import time


class My_Logger(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = []

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.log.append(message)  

    def start_new_round(self):
        self.log = []

    def save_round_to_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "w") as file_out:
            file_out.writelines(self.log)

introduction_message = """
    You are in the Kingdom of Dragons.

    In front of you, you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly
    and will share his treasure with you.
    
    The other dragon is hungry and will eat you on sight!
"""

## ------------------------
## print will call the write() method of object you assign to sys.stdout.
## ------------------------
sys.stdout = My_Logger()
## ------------------------

while (True):
    sys.stdout.start_new_round()

    #Introduction
    print(introduction_message)

    #letting the player input 1 or 2
    while True:
        select = input("cave 1,2,3,4 or 5 : ")
        if select in list("12345"):
            break

    #some statements of the game
    print("""\nYou approach the cave...""", select)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    print("""A large dragon jumps out in front of you!""")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    print("""He opens his jaws and ...""")
    time.sleep(1)

    #luck
    choices = ["Gobbles you down!", "Greets you before sharing his teature"]
    print("\n", random.choice(choices))
    time.sleep(2)
    
    again = input("\nDo you wanna play again?(y/n)")
    if again=="y":
        continue
    else:
        break

sys.stdout.save_round_to_file("log.txt")
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

That should give you a "log.txt" with your final round.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` has a file parameter.  By default, `print('something')` goes to sys.stdout.  But

```
out = open('output.txt', 'w')
print('final thing',file=out)
```

sends the text to 'output.txt'.  Check the docs for the meaning of the various mode parameters.  Make sure to close `out` before exiting.

Or use `out.write('final thing\n')` as someone else suggested.

To print to screen and and file, create the output string first.

```
text = 'final thing'
print(text)
print(text, file=out)
```

As an IDLE maintainer, I recommend against fiddling with sys.stdout.